# not show link prewiew in telegram open meta data

Tags: laravel-5, facebook-opengraph, telegram, share-open-graph

I,m using open graph meta tags and when share links has og meta tags not correct working in Telegram.
like link:
http://yaldayekavir.com/fa/product/223/%D9%85%D8%AD%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%A8

```
<meta property="og:description" content=". " /><meta property="og:title" content="محراب" /><meta property="og:type" content="product" /><meta property="og:url" content="http://yaldayekavir.com/fa/product/223/محراب" /><meta property="og:image" content="http://yaldayekavir.com/files/محراب - آبی.jpg" /><meta property="og:image:height" content="150" /><meta property="og:image:width" content="150" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I myself got this problem.
For images of the open graph meta data, you must use the decode url.

Answer (score 0):

put prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#" in html tag

see this code

```
<html prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
```

Answer (score 0):

because your image address (link) is http it must be https

i have this problem and active ssl for my website and change address to https